# how to use <script src=""> to insert a form in page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i have this script

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/formsaz/export.php?id=74459533"></script>
```

i want to paste it where i want and it loads a form for me. code inside export.php is:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function getQuery(name){
    if(name=(new RegExp('[?&amp;]'+encodeURIComponent(name)+'=([^&amp;]*)')).exec(location.search))
    return decodeURIComponent(name[1]);
    }

    var id = getQuery("id");

    document.write("<div style=\'width:100%; margin:0px auto\'><iframe src='http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/formsaz/formexport.php?id=" + id + "' scrolling='no' frameborder='0' hspace='0' width='100%' height='100%'></iframe></div>");

    </script>
```

this gets id from database and looks for data and then returns founded data to the page where that first script is pasted. but its not working! any suggestions on what should i do?

Comment: i think `<script>` is just for .js files...

Comment: You can't load a PHP-file (with HTML-tags) using `<script type="text/javascript" ...`. Not sure what your code is suppose to do, though? Can't you just do that with PHP without any JS?

Comment: why can't you make it a global function, include the script once and call the function?

Comment: And why cannot you just use an iframe, as your code is suggesting it?

Comment: why not `<?php include('export.php'); ?>` ??

Answer (score 0):

You can add the script dynamically (since your export.php return a javascript):

```
var jsElm = document.createElement("script");
jsElm.type = "application/javascript";
jsElm.src = "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/formsaz/export.php?id=74459533";
document.body.appendChild(jsElm);
```

Or add the `iframe`:

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.style.display = "none";
iframe.src = "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/formsaz/export.php?id=74459533";
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

As your script returns data, you should also consider an `ajax` call if possible.